# Elementary integral solution

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Can someone explain why $\int_{0}^{1} g'(t)\big(-\int_{0}^{t} g ds \big) dt  = \int_{0}^{1} g^2 dt$

I know this is quite trivial but I am not able to understand why. Maybe I am missing some fundamental property of integrals ( If so, can someone also provide a good reference to review them?).

Thank you very much

Comment: are you familiar with integration by parts?

Comment: Yes but I haven't understood how it has been used here... Please give me some hints

Comment: @Prettymath77: when you integrate a product like $uv$ by parts, you take the antiderivative of one of the factors, and there are just two options. Try them.

Comment: I keep trying, but I am unable since that $g'(t)$ outside the integral confuses me a lot. I really do not know how to solve it

Comment: Why did you use the stochastic integral tag?